# Cannot compile SwiftUI ForEach Table

Tags: foreach, swiftui, tableview

I'm trying to make a table view from dynamic array, but compiler cannot build it with unrelated error:
**The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions**

```
struct RecentView: View {
    @State var recentRooms: [[String: String]] = []

    @Binding var recentIsPressed: Bool
    @Binding var nextIsPressed: Bool
    @Binding var conferenceName: String

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    var body: some View {
        if let recent = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "recentRooms") as? [[String: String]] {
            recentRooms = recent
        }

        return VStack {

            ...

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(0 ..< recentRooms.count) { i in
                    Button(action: { self.meetingSelected(name: self.recentRooms[i]["name"] ?? "") }) {
                        HStack {
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("ProjectBlue"))
                                    .frame(width: 76, height: 76)
                                Text(self.recentRooms[i]["short_name"] ?? "")
                                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Bold", size: 36))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("AlmostWhite"))
                            }
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(self.recentRooms[i]["name"] ?? "")
                                    .font(.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 17))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("AlmostWhite"))
                                Text(self.recentRooms[i]["date"] ?? "")
                                    .font(.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 17))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("AlmostWhite"))
                                Text(self.recentRooms[i]["duration"] ?? "")
                                    .font(.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 17))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("AlmostWhite"))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: self.screenWidth, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func meetingSelected(name: String) {
        conferenceName = name
        nextIsPressed = true
        recentIsPressed = false
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong with the ForEach part?

Comment: So, why don't you do what compiler ask? Btw, it is very reasonable suggestion.

Comment: `ForEach(0 ..< recentRooms.count)` shouldn't be used with a dynamic content. Use `ForEach(recentRooms, id: \.self)` instead.

Comment: @Asperi, this is a very simple VStack, I do not see any benefit ofbreaking it up. The error seems to be misleading.

Comment: Your code will be cleaner and more readable for sure if you split ti.

Comment: Compiler "thinks different" about *simplicity* of your *simple VStack* ))

Comment: @pawello2222, I tried ForEach(recentRooms, id: \.self), but it gives same error, I also tried to use 5 and 0 instead of recentRooms.count - same compiler error

Comment: @dandepeched I'm not saying it will fix your code. I'm just saying you should use a `ForEach` loop differently. It might help you with other issues in the future.

Comment: @pawello2222, actually it fixed this! There was my mistake when changing code. Please add this as answer.

Comment: @Asperi, as you can see, the error was in syntaxis, not in VStack complexity. You shouldn't always blindly following compiler messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant of `ForEach` shouldn't be used with a dynamic content.

```
ForEach(0 ..< recentRooms.count)
```

If the `recentRooms` variable can be changed, use this instead:

```
ForEach(recentRooms, id: \.self)
```